# How to properly train an actor-critic

Tags: reinforcement-learning, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to figure out how the actor-critic method works.  And implement it in tensorflow.js

I have designed a small environment where you need a board to catch a falling ball. If caught +1 reward point, if not -1 reward point.

My implementation https://codepen.io/redrickShuhart/pen/popKmRj

The model is implemented with one body and two heads.

I am trying to train the model, but it seems to me that I have implemented the training process incorrectly.

Please help. Where am I wrong.
I would be glad to get a link to a tfjs example to help me figure it out.

```
train() {

    this.memory.reverse()
    let V_next = 0
    for (let s of this.memory) {
        let V_current = s.reward + V_next * this.gamma
        s['V'] = V_current
        s['V_next'] = V_next
        V_next = V_current
    }
    this.memory.reverse()

    for (let mem of this.memory) {

        let f = () => tf.tidy(() => {

            let {state, action, reward, next_state, V, V_next} = mem

            state = tf.tensor(state, [1, this.env.state_size])

            let [probs, value] = this.model.predict(state)

            let target_V = tf.tensor(V, [1, 1])
            let value_loss = tf.losses.meanSquaredError(target_V, value).asScalar()

            let advantages = new Array(this.action_size).fill(0)
            advantages[action] = V_next - V
            advantages = tf.tensor(advantages, [1, this.action_size])

            let policy_loss = tf.log(probs).mul(advantages).sum().mul(tf.scalar(-1)).asScalar()

            return policy_loss.add(value_loss)
        })

        let grads = tf.variableGrads(f).grads
        this.ALL_GRADIENTS.push(grads)

    }

    tf.tidy(() => {

        /* grads names */
        let keys = Object.keys(this.ALL_GRADIENTS[0])

        const new_grad = {}
        for (let key of keys) {
            new_grad[key] = null
        }

        for (let key in new_grad) {

            let grad_by_key = this.ALL_GRADIENTS.map(grad => grad[key])

            let mean = grad_by_key.reduce((prev_grad, cur_grad) => prev_grad.add(cur_grad)).div(tf.scalar(grad_by_key.length))

            new_grad[key] = mean
            tf.dispose(grad_by_key)
        }
        this.model.optimizer.applyGradients(new_grad)
    })

    // for (let grad of this.ALL_GRADIENTS) {
    //     this.model.optimizer.applyGradients(grad)
    // }

    this.memory = []
    tf.dispose(this.ALL_GRADIENTS)
    this.ALL_GRADIENTS = []

    // console.log(tf.memory())
}
```